# Alexa Skill Development, Fetching JSON Data from URL with request.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, alexa-skills-kit

Hi thanks for checking out my question. Im new the Alexa dev environment. Currently trying to fetch a JSON file from a url using the request.js

I have added the  package to package.json `"request": "^2.88.2"`

The request i cannot tell from the dev portal if its working, the function looks like:

```
const request = require('request');

request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.error('error:', error); 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
  console.log('body:', body);
});
```

cannot seem to get it to return anything I can see from the console

Answer (score 0):

According to the npm, `request` [package is deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), so I would not recommend to use it.
Instead you can use [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) package, like this:

```js
const JsonLoaderHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'JsonLoaderIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const yourJsonData = await fetch('https://your-endpoint.com/')
            .then(r => r.json())
            .catch(e => console.log(e) /** error handling here */);

        if (yourJsonData) {
            /** logic here */
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(`JSON object loaded`)
                //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
                .getResponse();    
        }

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(`Couldn't load a JSON object`)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```